# Case,Substring and concat within a cognos Data Item Expression

Tags: informix, cognos-10, isql

I'm scratching my head trying to work with time functions within Cognos 10.2.1 (Report Studio), using an Informix db as a data source.

My time field is stored as a smallint, 4 digits, representing the 24 hour clock.  I am trying to get the time to display as 6:00pm, 11:30am, 3:00pm, etc.  I have a separate data expression that calculates the string 'AM' or 'PM' depending on the hour value, but I'm running into some errors when doing the overall concat/substring function.

```
case when char_length([Query1].[beg_tm]) = 4 
then (substring(cast([StartTime], char(5)), 1, 2)) || ':' || (substring   (cast   ([StartTime], char(5)), 3, 2))  || ([beg_AMPMcalc])
when char_length([Query1].[beg_tm]) = 3
then (substring(cast([StartTime], char(5)), 1, 1)) || ':' || (substring(cast    ([StartTime], char(5)), 3, 2))  || ([beg_AMPMcalc])
else '--'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE; at least you then only have to deal with converting 24 hour clock to 12 hour clock.  Is midnight stored as 0 and noon as 1200, and the minute before midnight as 2359?  Cognos uses a fairly modern version of Informix, I believe, so you should be able to use the TO_CHAR function:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS times;
CREATE TEMP TABLE times(p_time SMALLINT);
INSERT INTO times VALUES(0);
INSERT INTO times VALUES(59);
INSERT INTO times VALUES(100);
INSERT INTO times VALUES(845);
INSERT INTO times VALUES(1159);
INSERT INTO times VALUES(1200);
INSERT INTO times VALUES(1259);
INSERT INTO times VALUES(1300);
INSERT INTO times VALUES(1815);
INSERT INTO times VALUES(2359);

SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT HOUR TO MINUTE, "%I:%M %p"),
       p_time,
       DATETIME(00:00) HOUR TO MINUTE + MOD(p_time, 100) UNITS MINUTE + (p_time/100) UNITS HOUR,
       TO_CHAR(DATETIME(00:00) HOUR TO MINUTE + MOD(p_time, 100) UNITS MINUTE + (p_time/100) UNITS HOUR, "%I:%M %p")
  FROM times;
```

Output:

```
03:49 AM      0   00:00   12:00 AM
03:49 AM     59   00:59   12:59 AM
03:49 AM    100   01:00   01:00 AM
03:49 AM    845   08:45   08:45 AM
03:49 AM   1159   11:59   11:59 AM
03:49 AM   1200   12:00   12:00 PM
03:49 AM   1259   12:59   12:59 PM
03:49 AM   1300   13:00   01:00 PM
03:49 AM   1815   18:15   06:15 PM
03:49 AM   2359   23:59   11:59 PM
```

I'm using a database server that has its local time set to UTC, and I'm in time zone -07:00 (US/Pacific); the current time isn't the middle of the night where I am.